# Kdenlive ビルド時のエラーの解消方法について

Tags: c++

私は現在Kdenliveという動画編集ツールをGitからダウンロードして、
Craftを使ってビルドして使いたいと思っています。

理由としては、C ++のソースコードをコーディングして、
KdenliveのUIや機能の追加や削除を独自に構築して使いたいと思っています。

今は、CraftをGitからダウンロードしてインストールまでができました。
インストールしたCraftを使って、Kdenliveのビルドを行いましたら画像のようなエラーが起きてしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**エラーコード**

```
-- Checking for module 'mlt++-7'
--   No package 'mlt++-7' found
CMake Error at C:/CraftRoot/dev-utils/cmake-base/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find MLT (missing: MLT_LIBRARIES MLTPP_LIBRARIES MLT_INCLUDE_DIR
  MLTPP_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "7.0.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/CraftRoot/dev-utils/cmake-base/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindMLT.cmake:65 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/CraftRoot/build/_/3377f5a/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/CraftRoot/build/_/3377f5a/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Action: compile for kde/kdemultimedia/kdenlive:21.08.1 FAILED
*** Craft all failed: kde/kdemultimedia/kdenlive after 12 seconds ***
fatal error: package kde/kdemultimedia/kdenlive all failed
Craft stopped with out completing ['kde/kdemultimedia/kdenlive']
```

こちらのエラーの解決方法が分からず困っております。
できる限り分かりやすく教えていただけますと幸いです。

実行環境として、PCはWindows10、コンパイラーにはVisual Studio 2019を使っています。

Craftは下記URLからダウンロードしました。
https://github.com/KDE/craft

Kdenliveは下記URLからダウンロードしました。
https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージから読み取れる部分についてのみ回答してみます。

---

ビルドするにはいくつかの依存ライブラリがあり、そのうちの一つが見つからないようです。

> ```
> No package 'mlt++-7' found
> ```

kdenlive のドキュメントを見ると、ビルドする際のメインターゲットは Linux (Ubuntu, Arch) だが、依存ライブラリが条件を満たしていればその他の環境でも構築できるだろう、と記載されています。

まずはこの辺りの条件を満たしているのかを確認してみてください。

https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive/blob/master/dev-docs/build.md

> Qt >= 5.7, KF5 >= 5.50, MLT >= 6.20.0

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
URLの記事を読ませていただきましたが、依存ライブラリが条件などの手順がいまいち分かりません。
また、PowerSellでMLTのバージョンを確認した結果、『melt.exe 7.1.0』とでました。（コマンド：melt -version）

Craftをインストールする際にできる、『C:\CraftRoot\etc\blueprints\locations\craft-blueprints-kde\libs\mlt』の中にある『mlt.py』を見た結果バージョン６のデータを取ってこようとしているみたいです。
そこで書き換えましたが、結果は同じでした。